# Passing return value of anonymous function to another function

Tags: jquery

I have to pass return value of an anonymous function as a argument to another function hello1()

```
hello1 = function(x,m) { console.log(m) };

return $(this).each(function() {
        var self = this;
        hello1(something , function(){ return(this); });
});
```

When i do console.log(m) it shows ... return(this); instead of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m is a function, so to get its result you must call it.

```
hello1 = function(x,m) { console.log(m()) };
```

Comment: Was JUST going to say that myself. :P

Comment: No problem. Gotta type faster @DanRedux!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just pass in "self"?

```
hello1 = function(x,m) { console.log(m) }; 

return $(this).each(function() { 
        var self = this; 
        hello1(something , self }); 
});
```